# How to find X Y coordinates for creating labels on a pie chart (ReactJS)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, charts

I need some help getting over the finish line. I am creating a pie chart from scratch as we are not allowed to use any libraries. I got to the chart creating, however I cannot figure out how to get the right X and Y coordinates for the label. I am sure there are some calculations involved but I can't seem to figure out the right one.

I have a jsFiddle that has my code up on it, currently I randomized the X and Y coordinate to display Test anywhere. I would like to know how to add it to the correct designation.

https://jsfiddle.net/v9ex8zwh/

```
let slices = [
  {percent: 0.7307692307692307, color: "green", asset_type: "Multifamily"},
  {percent: 0.07692307692307693, color: "red", asset_type: "Industrial"}, 
  {percent: 0.07692307692307693, color: "yellow", asset_type: "Special Purpose"}, 
  {percent: 0.07692307692307693, color: "grey", asset_type: "Vacant Land"},
  {percent: 0.038461538461538464, color: "blue", asset_type: "Mixed Use"}
]


class PieChart extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        let viewBox=` -${this.props.width} -${this.props.width} ${this.props.width*2} ${this.props.width*2}`

        let transform = "rotate(0 0 0)"; //if you want it rotated a certain angle change the first number in the this transform object
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <svg width={this.props.width} height={this.props.width} viewBox={viewBox} transform = {transform}>
                        {getPaths(this.props.slices, this.props.width)}hello
                    </svg>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function getCoordinatesForPercent(percent) {
    const x = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * percent);
    const y = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * percent);
    return [x, y];
}

let cumulativePercent = 0;

const getPaths = (slices, size) => {
    let paths = [];

    slices.forEach(slice => {

        let [startX, startY] = getCoordinatesForPercent(cumulativePercent);

        cumulativePercent += slice.percent;

        const [endX, endY] = getCoordinatesForPercent(cumulativePercent);

        // if the slice is more than 50%, take the large arc (the long way around)
        const largeArcFlag = slice.percent > .5 ? 1 : 0;

        // create an array and join it just for code readability
        const pathData = [
            `M ${startX * size} ${startY * size}`, // Move
            `A ${size} ${size} 0 ${largeArcFlag} 1 ${endX * size} ${endY * size}`, // Arc (size is same as radius)
            `L 0 0`, // Line
        ].join(' ');

 paths.push(<g overflow='hidden'><path d={pathData} stroke={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'} fill={slice.color}/><text x={(Math.random() * 70)} y ={(Math.random() * 120)}> + Test</text></g>)
    });
    return paths;
}

ReactDOM.render(<PieChart slices={slices} width={250}/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: I don't think your jsfiddle matches the code you have here. Also, a little hint, you can declare `width` as a variable inside your render and then you don't have to write `this.props.width` ten times. Aka write `const { width } = this.props;` inside your render function and then just use `width`.

Comment: I copied the code I posted into a new jsFiddle(with React) and it showed the same results, seems strange. As for the { width } thing, thanks. I am working off someone else's example and didn't bother changing their code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mouse event to find out.

a POC:

```js
const circ = document.querySelector('.circ');
const x = document.querySelector('.x');
const y = document.querySelector('.y');

circ.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  x.innerHTML = 'x: ' + e.offsetX;
  y.innerHTML = 'y: ' + e.offsetY;
});
```

```css
.circ {
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="circ"></div>

<div class="x"></div>
<div class="y"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I am trying to find the X and Y coordinates of each slice before rendering it so that I can append the labels to each slice dynamically.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand you again... can you upload an image with what you want?